# router outside canActivate: [AuthGuard] doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, router, guard

I have a problem with my routing.

I tried to used this code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
      { path: 'events', component: EventsComponent },
      { path: 'package', component: PackageComponent },
      { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' },
  { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: "usersforgetpassword", component: ResetPassComponent }
];
```

[image]

Doesn't work navigate, forgot password (ResetPassComponent) and new account(RegisterComponent ).

Html code:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/usersforgetpassword']" class="text-center footnote">
            <FormattedString>
                <Span text="Forgot password?  "></Span>
            </FormattedString>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/register']" class="text-center footnote">
            <FormattedString>
                <Span text="New Account "></Span>
            </FormattedString>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
```

Please, can you ask me, what is the problem in my router? I can't understand.

Thnx

Comment: are you using `page-router-outlet` ?

Comment: Yes `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please place these

```
{ path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: "usersforgetpassword", component: ResetPassComponent }
```

Before

```
 { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard route should always be in the end, otherwise routes below that won't work as it matches all possible strings.

Refer : https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration